# How does this JavaScript function create a GUID?

Tags: javascript, guid

I came across this JavaScript function and I don't understand quite what it's doing, especially with the use of 0xF.

What does the 0xF do, exactly.  It looks like a null nibble to me.

```
function()
{
    var g = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        g += Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xF).toString(0xF)
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0xF` == 15. It's simply hexadecimal notation.

However, that snippet is not actually creating a GUID, it's just stringing a bunch of random integers together. It's not possible to create a GUID in JavaScript, because generating one requires parameters that the VM can't access (network address, etc).

---

See also my answer to this question: [How to create a GUID in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-in-javascript)

Comment: I know it was hexadecimal,  I just didn't realise that it was being converted according to the ASCII standard. I thought it was shorthand for 0xFF.

Comment: ASCII has nothing to do with it. 0xF is 15, 0xFF is 255, 0xFFF is 4095. Like in decimal numbers, undefined digits in hex default to 0.

Answer (score 1):

0xF is hex notation

EDIT:

It looks like it's picking a random character 0-9 A-F 32 times

Answer (score 1):

All it's doing is creating random number s and converting them to hex.

I just did a little investigating . . . it is taking a random number, multiplying it by 15 (0xF == 15) and then converting it to hex . . . the toString argument takes a radix.  That's the same as saying 0xF.toString(10).  That'll convert 0xF to decimal and return "15."